# Trying to create a 6 level combobox that uses JSON on the backend

Tags: jquery, json, combobox, getjson, chained

I have been looking at a lot of combo boxes but have yet to see one that uses
JSON on the backend or one that is more than six fields. I was trying to use
http://www.appelsiini.net/2010/jquery-chained-selects as a resource but am
having trouble implementing JSON at the backend. Would someone mind giving me
a hand?

Comment: Please add some code to show what you have at the moment. Currently you have not provided enough detail.

Comment: What kind of trouble are you having with JSON?  Parsing it?  Navigating the object structure?  I'm pretty sure the Chained plugin will be able to accommodate your UI scheme once you get the JSON figured out.

Comment: If it helps any, I am trying to emulate this for our site
http://www.nixonnow.com/watch-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<p class="notice" >
 <select id="forGender" >
 <option value="" >-- </option >
 <option value="m" >Guys </option >
 <option value="f" >Girls </option > </select >

<select disabled="" id="displayType" > <option value="" >-- </option > </select >
 <select disabled="" id="material" > <option value="" >-- </option > </select >
 <select disabled="" id="color" > <option value="" >-- </option > </select >
 <select disabled="" id="price" > <option value="" >-- </option > </select >
 <select disabled="" id="custom" > <option value="" >-- </option > </select >
          $(function(){
            $("#displayType").chained("#gender");
            $("#band <aterial").chained("#displayType");
            $("#color").chained("#bandMaterial");
            $("#caseDiameter").chained("#color");
            $("#bandWidth").chained("#caseDiameter");
            $("#keywords").chained("#bandWidth");
          });
           </script >
 </p >

json

{
    "idName": "The Time Teller",
     "forGender": "m",
     "displayType": "analog",
     "bandType": "plastic",
     "caseDiameter": 1.5,
     "caseThickness": 0.5,
     "bandWidth": 0.78,
    "items": [
        {
            "color1": "white",
            "color2": "none",
            "price": 59.99,
            "cat": "29400",
            "img": "155320-0002-front",
            "sku": 155411 
        },
        {
            "color1": "blue",
            "color2": "none",
            "price": 59.99,
            "cat": "32579",
            "img": "155411-0005-front",
            "sku": 160041 
        },
        {
            "color1": "black",
            "color2": "pink",
            "price": 59.99,
            "cat": "38404",
            "img": "160041-0001-front",
            "sku": 155320 
        } 
    ],
    "specialInformation": {
        "restrictions": "Available for US customers only.",
        "details": [
            "Custom 3 hand Japanese quartz movement.",
            "100 meter molded polycarbonate case.",
            "Hardened mineral crystal.",
            "Locking looper and polycarbonate buckle." 
        ],
        "desc": "Nixon's The Time Teller watch keeps it simpleton with hard case and custom molded polyurethane band." 
    } 
}